# Which of these two people killed this spy family?

Tags: the-americans

Warning: This entire question contains spoilers for season 2 of *The Americans*.

---

Who killed Emmet, Leanne, and Amelia Connors? In one episode, I remember a scene where Claudia was talking to Elizabeth in a car where Claudia revealed that she had killed the Connors because she formerly told them information about herself that compromised her. But then later, Jared Connors revealed that he had killed his own family. So who actually killed the Connors? What was Claudia talking about?

Comment: Are you sure?  I can't remember a scene where Claudia tells Elizabeth this...  Which episode was it?  I remember a scene where Claudia tells Elizabeth to that it may have been her *fault* the Connors were killed (but not that she herself had killed them), because Claudia had talked too freely to a lover, and thus may have exposed herself and the Connors -- this was just after P&E posed as CIA-agents to interrogate the military-officer, and concluded he hadn't killed them.

Comment: @BaardKopperud I can't remember with certainty but I recall Claudia telling Elizabeth that she had killed them. In a few months before season 4 comes out I'll rewatch the series and update this.

Comment: **S2E6** Dialog: **Elizabeth**: *if Larrick didn't kill Emmett and Leanne, who do we look at next?* **Claudia**: *me. I got involved with someone while I was working with Emmett and Leanne. I didn't plan on it, but... this business can be lonely. I didn't tell him who I really was, of course. Until one day I did. I trusted him. I don't know that he betrayed me. But ever since the murders, I've been plagued with the thought that he told someone, that I may have compromised the safety of my own agents.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jared killed his own parents because he **wanted** to be a spy for the Russians, and they were trying to discourage him.

At different points in the second season, different parties had varied other motivations, including Larrick and Claudia. It turned out it wasn’t either of them. The killer was the Connors’ own son, Jared, who had been groomed as a second-generation illegal behind his parents’ backs (by Kate - not Claudia), and decided to homicidally fight them when they objected to his attempt to follow in their stealth footsteps.

It was Kate who converted Jared to the cause, at the Centre’s insistence, without parental permission. This also explains more clearly why Claudia got booted from her post and Kate was installed in her job. The Centre knew that the best way to win over a teenage boy was by assigning a young, pretty blonde to do the persuading.

To answer for Claudia's comments, she was trying to manufacture a believeable scenario, because she knows that Elizabeth's children are future prospective Russian spies, and she is unsure of their devotion to Russia to also similarly disallow it. She had to have a cover for the recruitment, which was the true motivation behind the killings. She was also trying to look good to retain her job, by taking credit.

Comment: did Kate have blonde hair?  my memory might be slipping but I could have sworn she was a red head.